# Polars Extensions - Custom Printing/Display

Tags: python, python-polars, rust-polars

I now have a set of operations on Polars dataframes that I would like to consolidate under a Rust+python polars extension.

While doing this, I wanted to override the default formatting/printing of the dataframe. e.g., my dataframes have a persistent set of columns, and the order and position of those columns is important - so I'd like to reorder the columns whenever the dataframe is displayed. I believe this code is in `fmt.rs`?

Could I have some guidance on what options I have to implement this and hook in my own printing format - the extension documentation mentions adding methods under namespaces. The only idea I have so far is to add a `df.myns().reorder_columns()` style method, but that seems cumbersome.

I see there are 2 styles of extending polars by the way:

- the geopolars way, which seems to subclass pl.DataFrame at the rust level
- the API way using the `pl.api.register_XXX_namespace`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of overriding the formatting, perhaps it's possible to have a "custom schema" object where you can keep certain columns in a specific order? Interesting question - could be worth asking on [Polars Discord](https://discord.gg/4UfP5cfBE7) as it probably requires a dev to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you always want a df that has columns ['foo', 'bar'] to have those to be the furthest left regardless of how they're actually defined.

You'd have to monkey patch some combination of `_repr_html_`, `__repr__`, and `__str__` depending on your environment.

Say you're in VSC where typing `df` at the console invokes `_repr_html_` then you could do...

```
oldrepr=pl.DataFrame._repr_html_
def newrepr(self):
    if "foo" in self.columns and "bar" in self.columns:
        return oldrepr(self.select(pl.col('foo','bar'), pl.exclude('foo','bar')))
    else: 
        return oldrepr(self)
pl.DataFrame._repr_html_=newrepr
```

Now if you do...

```
df=pl.DataFrame({
    'a':[1,2,3],
    'bar':[2,3,4],
    'foo':[9,1,5]
})
df
```

you get...

[image]

Comment: Thats an interesting option I had not considered. I would have preferred to do the formatting at the Rust level - so that the display/format is a property of my extended dataframe. Perhaps this is not necessary. Your suggestion does seem to achieve everything I was after, and (for now at least) I would only really be operating on the dataframe at the python level...